# Opera target Attribute

Tags: html, anchor, opera, target

so the compatibility difference between browsers is driving me nuts
  more so the rendering of html & css

so in opera Version 11.64  `<a href="/folder/" target="_blank">link</a>`

works as expected in firefox but opera doesn't open in new window

Comment: What value you are using? and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you haven't got the "ignore target" user preference flag set? Visit about:config and search for "target"

Comment: thanks man i thought it was in the config        opera:config  >  User Prefs  >  Ignore Target Solved

Comment: I added an answer so that others with the same problem can find the solution easily. Please accept the answer by clicking the green check mark. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

This is controlled by a preference in Opera: opera:config > User Prefs > Ignore Target .